# replacewith jquery

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I have list generated by ajax call like this

```
<ul id="list">
   <li name="A">some val</li>
   <li name="B">some val</li>
   <li name="C">some val</li>
</ul>
```

with a setinterval, the same ajax call will create a list like this

```
<ul id="listClone">
  <li name="A">some new val</li>
  <li name="B">some cccc val</li>
  <li name="C">some ddd val</li>
</ul>
```

after I get the listClone, I need to replace the list "A" with listClone A.

How do I do that with jQuery?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are trying to replace the entire list or just the `li` element with `name=A` but if it is the latter that's what my answer addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just want to replace the li element:

```
$('#list li[name=A]').html($('#listclone li[name=A]').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#list').replaceWith('<ul id="listClone"><li name="A">some new val</li><li name="B">some cccc val</li><li name="C">some ddd val</li></ul>');`

Suggestion:

Try keeping the new list id as 'list` rather than 'listClone' since this will NOT work the next time you call the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list").html($("#listClone").remove().html());
```

listClone is removed. and list's html is replaced with listClone's html.

Answer (score 0):

To remove whole `#list` with `#listClone` you can do:

```
$('#list').replaceWith($('#listClone'));
```

To remove a particular list item of `#list` with a `#listClone` item you can do:

```
$('#list').eq(0).replaceWith($('#listClone').eq(0)); // replace first element
```

or  using `name` attribute

```
$('#list li[name=A]').replaceWith($('#listClone li[name=A]')); // replace first element
```

Also do with `.html()`:

```
$('#list li[name=A]').html($('#listClone li[name=A]').html()); // replace first element
```

Also can use `.text()`

```
$('#list li[name=A]').text($('#listClone li[name=A]').text()); // replace first element
```